# AppBarLayout background rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm implementing a custom header for my app. In AppBarLayout I'm using Toolbar and my custom layout (named CustomHeader).
My CustomHeader has bottom left and bottom right rounded corners. To show properly I set `android:background="@null"`.

Layout for appBarLayout with custom header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/logoAppbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgToolbarLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_toolbar_logo" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <CustomHeader
        android:id="@+id/stepOneHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:selected_step="1"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/stepProgressBar"
        style="@style/AppTheme.StepProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="0"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And this is my CustomHeader's layout. I omitted some parts for brevity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_bg">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/headerDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_divider_border"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            ...
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is CustomHeader's background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="22dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="22dp"/>
</shape>
```

What is going on is: no matter what I do, at the AppBarLayout bottom borders I always have a white background. The image is below:
[image: White corners]

Notice the screens continues after header.

I tried 2 solutions founded on SO:
[ActionBar with rounded edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417161/actionbar-with-rounded-edges)
[How to make toolbar with rounded corners and elevation inside appbarlayout? Like this picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536349/how-to-make-toolbar-with-rounded-corners-and-elevation-inside-appbarlayout-like)

My issue is pretty much the same as the second link.
Any of them worked for me. I only want this white background transparent.

Comment: Set app:elevation="0dp" in AppBarLayout. Thats it.

Comment: I think the background you're seeing is the value of the `windowBackground` attribute, which is expected since every activity / window has a default background. What result do you want exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to AppBarLayout xml:

app:elevation="0dp"

Comment: Please explain how does this work?